# How to document an web component with jsdoc3

Tags: documentation, jsdoc, web-component, jsdoc3, x-tag

What would be the way to document a web component using [jsdoc3](http://usejsdoc.org/)

Here is an example of web component registered with x-tag.

```js
xtag.register('x-analytics',
{
    lifecycle : {
        created : function(){
        }
    },
    accessors : {
        code : {
            attribute : true
        },
        domain : {
            attribute : true
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since X-Tag is also just JavaScript, you can simply use the corresponding annotations provided by jsdoc. So things like `@memberof` etc.

However, Web Components syntax can have its own kind of additional meaning. For example you probably want an annotation for `@element` or `@lifecycleCallback` and stuff like this. This is not provided by jsdoc and therefore e.g. Polymer uses it's own documentation annotation using `core-component-page`.

You either use what jsdoc provides and see what annotations fit best for your use case, or you use something like [dgeni](https://github.com/angular/dgeni) which lets you build a documentation tool pipe entirely from scratch, so you have full control over your annotations etc.

Comment: " you can simply use the corresponding annotations provided by jsdoc " : this is my question : is there a usual way to do it ?  Should I use `@lends`, creates types with `@typedef`, etc.

Comment: There's nothing that stops you from that.